# How to disable automatic downcasing in NestJS' typeORM query to my postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM to create and manage my DataBase using TypeORM Entities.

I have a very peculiar relation as such

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  login: string;

  @Column()
  nickname: string;

  @Column()
  wins: number;

  @Column()
  looses: number;

  @Column()
  current_status: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User)
  @JoinTable()
  friends: User[];

  @ManyToMany(() => MatchHistory)
  @JoinTable()
  match_histories: MatchHistory[];
}
```

Where User has a ManyToMany relationship with itself. Because of this, typical tools do not work correctly (I haven't found a way to access a User's friends with TypeORM's tools).

So I am doing a good old SQL request as such:

```
const res = await this.manager.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id IN (SELECT F.userId_2 AS Friends FROM user_friends_user F WHERE F.userId_1=?);", [user.id]);
```

This can be translated as "get all the users who's ID is in the friend list of user `user`.

The problem is that I have noticed that all my requests seem to be downcased. When doing this I face the `column f.userid_2 does not exist`.

I do not know if it is TypeORM or Postgres which downcases my requests, all I want is it to stop doing so. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something Postgres does by default. If you need to use uppercase values, you need to pass a string literal to Postgres. In your case, that would look like

```js
const res = await this.manager.query(
  'SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id IN (SELECT "F"."userId_2" AS "Friends" FROM user_friends_user "F" WHERE "F"."userId_1"=?);',
  [user.id]
);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. little precision that, apparently, to the the parameters the correct syntax is `@1` (postgres seems to be the only system using this syntax)

Comment: Edit: it is actually $1, as in bash